# How to efficiently check a list item with all other list items?

Tags: javascript, optimization

Is there any way to optimize this method of searching?

```
for (var i=0;i<dots.length;i++) {
        var blist = [];
        for (var n=0;n<dots.length;n++) {
            if (dots[n][1]>(dots[i][1]-90) 
            && dots[n][1]<(dots[i][1]+90) 
            && dots[n][2]>(dots[i][2]-90) 
            && dots[n][2]<(dots[i][2]+90)) {
                if (!(n === i)) blist.push(n);
            }
        }
```

`dots[x][1]` is the x-coordinate and `dots[x][2]` is the y-coordinate.

I have 1000 dots, and need to find the dots surrounding each dot, so that results in the

```
if (dots[n][1]>(dots[i][1]-90) 
&& dots[n][1]<(dots[i][1]+90) 
&& dots[n][2]>(dots[i][2]-90) 
&& dots[n][2]<(dots[i][2]+90))
```

Running a million times a second, so is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Put the dots into a data structure.

Comment: `var n=i+1` on the inner loop initialisation? (With maybe some extra logic if you need two-way matches - what do you do with `blist`?)

Comment: @nnnnnn after this one dot is picked from blist for that dot to follow, so essentially is searches for all the dots nearby and picks one as a target

Comment: Sort the dots by position.

Comment: Is there a good reason that `dots[i]` looks like `[100, 200]` rather than `{x: 100, y: 200}`, (or whatever values are appropriate) which you could access as `dots[i].x` and  `dot[i].y`?  That would seem a more straightforward format.

Comment: @ScottSauyet No good reason, I was just used to arrays rather than dictionaries. There's 5 things in each dot array I think..

Comment: Use a two-dimensional [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), or kind of a [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using a data structure for your dots like this

```
var Dot = function(){
 var x = 0;
 var y = 0;
 var Up;
 var Right;
 var Left;
 var Down;

 function init(xVal,yVal)
 {
  x = xVal;
  y = yVal;
 }

 function GetUp()
 {
  return Up;
 }

 function SetUp(UpDot)
 {
  Up = UpDot;
 }

 return 
 {
  init: init,
  GetUp: GetUp,
  SetUp: SetUp
 };
};
```

and then use it like this

```
var Dots = [];
var firstDot = new Dot();
Dots.push(firstDot);
var secondDot = new Dot();
secondDot.init(0,90);
secondDot.SetUp(firstDot);
Dots.push(secondDot);
```

Obviously, more would need to be added and configured to match your situation. However, what this would allow you to do was iterate through dots and then check weather there existed a near dot making the time O(n) instead of O(n^2) and thus saving you 900,000 checks.

Comment: So how would you iterate through the dots?

Comment: `for( var i = 0, max = Dots.length; i < max; i++){ if(Dots[i].HasNeighbor()){}};` Iterate through the array of dots, and then perform a check on each one. You could set them up so that they had a simple boolean which was returned from `HasNeighbor` to squeeze some extra speed out of the operation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll restructure the whole thing and see if I can push draws out faster.

Comment: @LiamBigelow: I'm not understanding how this helps, and certainly not how this reduces from O(n^2) to O(n).  I see nothing to say that only certain indices could supply neighbors.  Unless I'm missing something, these coordinates are likely scattered and we're trying to find the ones close to one another, not the neighbors on a fixed grid.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Correct, scattered and moving. Do you not think that Objects would be faster? Or would they essentially be the same

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Constructing the grid is just as important as the structure. If you do not understand how data structures can help reduce time complexity, perhaps you should read up on algorithms.

Comment: @TravisJ: The point was that this is the **wrong** data structure.  There are not a fixed set of neighbors to check; you have to find a way to compare with all other points.  I see nothing in your suggestion that would help reduce the overall complexity.  Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: @TravisJ: Perhaps I was misunderstanding.  As I contemplate how to do this problem, I think maybe my solution is similar to what you were trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

One way to cut your time in half would be not to double-check each pair:

```
for (var i = 0, len = dots.length; i < len - 1; i++) {
    var blist = [];
    for (var n = i + 1; n < len; n++) {
        if (dots[n][1]>(dots[i][1]-90) 
        && dots[n][1]<(dots[i][1]+90) 
        && dots[n][2]>(dots[i][2]-90) 
        && dots[n][2]<(dots[i][2]+90)) {
            blist.push(i);
            blist.push(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the change in loop boundaries.  This allows me to check each pair only once and skip the `(n === i)` check.

I also cache `dot.length`, probably not a big deal, but worth doing for a tight loop.

Still, that should be an improvement of more than 50%.  While that could help, it's not the orders of magnitude change that might be required for this sort of issue.

Comment: But then say i is 20, wouldn't the second loop only check numbers above 20?

Comment: Yes, but that's the point.  (There was a bug, fixed above.)  Your original loop compared, say dot20 with dot37, pushing dot37 onto your list.  Then later it compared dot37 with dot20, pushing dot20 onto the list.  It did this comparison twice, for no good reason.  This one only does it once.

Comment: I see what you mean but after each loop the list is wiped. Each dot picks a dot around it, rinse, repeat. The dots are moving

Comment: No, I'm talking about your initial version, in the iteration where i = 20 and n = 37.  Later you have to do i = 37, n = 20.  You do essentially the same comparison in those two cases.  My suggestion is simply that this duplication is unnecessary.  You can avoid it by making the inner loop a little more focused.

Comment: I understand that double check, but not how you propose to fix it.

Comment: My code sample above starts iterating `n` at `i + 1`.  That's all it takes.  For any pair of indices, say 34 and 11, they will be tested when `i` has the value of the smaller one, 11, and `n` has the value of the larger one, 34.

Comment: But say the loop is i=1, and it checks all of n. you wind up with blist, which is all of the dots close to i. One of these is picked and we move on to i=2, at which point blist is cleared NB:`blist=[]`. If on i=23 we see that it is close to 48, how would we remember when i=48 that is was close to 23

Comment: You're right.  I missed the fact that `blist` is continually reinitialized.  And I am missing something fundamental altogether.  Where do you do anything with the values in `blist`?  I was thinking that this was a list of all points within 90 units of another.  Is it used for something else inside the outer loop?

Comment: http://reasoner.comoj.com/swarm/

That is the full thing (Uses a ton of cpu, beware), audio visualization.

http://reasoner.comoj.com/swarm/swarm.js

That is the full, very sloppy code.

Comment: Essentially for each i it gets all near dots and picks one, and assigns that dot it's target, which is part of it's array. When the draw function is called it uses this target to move the dot.

Comment: Very interesting stuff.  Don't have time now to investigate further, I'm afraid.  But I wish you the best of luck.  A very pretty demo.

Comment: Thank you, besides I discovered it's my draw function doing the worst damage, not the settarget,.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of a solution.  It may be the same idea TravisJ was suggesting, although that's not clear to me.  It really is only a sketch, and would take significant code to implement.

If you partition your space into 90 unit x 90 unit sections, then a dot in a particular section can only be close enough to a dot in that section or to a dot in one of that section's eight neighbors.  This could significantly reduce the number of pairs you have to compare.  The cost, of course is algorithmic complexity:

- First create a data structure to represent your grid sections.  They can probably be represented just by top-left corners, since their heights and widths would be fixed at 90, except maybe at the trailing edges, where it probably wouldn't matter.  Assuming a rectangular surface, each one could have three, five, or eight neighbors (corners, edges, inner sections respectively).
- Loop through your dots, determining which section they live in.  If your total grid starts at 0, this should be relatively straightforward, using some `Math.floor(something / 90)` operations.
- For each section, run the loop above on itself and each of its neighbors to find the set of matches.  You can use the shortened version of the loop from my earlier answer.
- For a further optimization, you can also reduce the number of neighbors to check.  If Section3,7 does a comparison with Section3,8, then there is no reason for Section3,8 to also do the comparison with Section3,7.  So you check only a certain subset of the neighbors, say those whose x and y components of their section numbers are greater than or equal to their own.

I have not tested this, except in my head.  It should work, but I have not tried to write any code.  And the code would not be trivial.  I don't think it's weeks of work, but it's not something to whip together in a few minutes either.

I believe it could significantly increase the speed, but that will depend upon how many matches there are, how many dots there are relative to the number of sections.

Comment: But if this is run 5 times a second, it seems like it would be more processor heavy having to recalculate what squares each dot is in all the time.

Comment: But that's an O(n) operation.  If you can do this to reduce the remaining O(n^2) operations, it's likely a good trade-off, at least for larger values of n.